# Rails 3: How to render ERb template in rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, erb

I am rendering a pretty huge sitemap HTML file with rake. Unfortunately, the code breaks when I migrate to rails 3. My current code looks like this:

```
@controller = ActionController::Base.new
@controller.request = ActionController::TestRequest.new
@controller.instance_eval do
  @url = ActionController::UrlRewriter.new(request, {})
end

# collect data, open output file file

template = ERB.new(IO.read("#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/views/sitemap/index.html.erb"))
f.puts(template.result(binding))
```

This code worked in 2.3, but breaks in Rails 3 as url_for does not access @controller anymore, but controller. (I think that's why.)

```
undefined local variable or method `controller' for #<Object:0x3794c>
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:31:in `url_options'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:132:in `url_for'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:99:in `url_for'
(erb):5
/Users/me/Documents/Projects/zvg2/lib/tasks/zvg.rake:452
```

I also tried creating an ActionView to do it like that:

```
av = ActionView::Base.new(Rails::Application::Configuration.new(Rails.root).view_path, {
  # my assigns
}, @controller)
av.class_eval do
  include ApplicationHelper
end
f.puts(av.render(:template => "sitemap/index.html"))
```

But the problem seems to be the same, although ActionView::Base.new takes my controller.

```
undefined local variable or method `controller' for nil:NilClass
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:31:in `url_options'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:132:in `url_for'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:99:in `url_for'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:132:in `url_for'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:99:in `url_for'
/Users/me/Documents/Projects/zvg2/app/views/sitemap/index.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_sitemap_index_html_erb__757224102_30745030_0'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:135:in `send'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:135:in `render'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:54:in `instrument'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:127:in `render'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:59:in `_render_template'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:56:in `_render_template'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:26:in `render'
/Users/me/Documents/Projects/zvg2/lib/tasks/zvg.rake:450
```

What's the best practice for rendering a template with rake that uses url_for and link_to? I bet as Rails just got more modular, there should be an easy way for just this?

Thanks in advance! Jan

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One of the approaches works when I include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers instead of ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper. This works for now:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers # brings ActionDispatch::Routing::UrlFor
include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper

av = ActionView::Base.new(Rails.root.join('app', 'views'))
av.assign({
  :regions => @regions,
  :courts_by_region => @courts_by_region,
  :cities_by_region => @cities_by_region,
  :districts_by_region => @districts_by_region
})
f = File.new(file_name, 'w')
f.puts(av.render(:template => "sitemap/index.html"))
f.close
```

Hope this helps others. If there is a better solution, I'd be interested.

Also, how do I automatically get a hash of assigns from binding?

Answer (score 14):

I was successfull by doing something like this:

```
class Template < ActionView::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper

  def default_url_options
    {host: 'yourhost.org'}
  end
end  

template = Template.new(Rails.root.join('app', 'views'))
template.assign(attendee: @attendee)
template.render(template: 'sitemap/index.html.erb')
```

Comment: One thing is you do not need `.html.erb` in template name for Ruby On Rails 3.2.x. With `.html.erb` it produce deprecation warnings and asks to use `:handlers` and `:formats`

Answer (score 7):

This is what worked for me (Rails 3):

```
class TaskActionView < ActionView::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include ApplicationHelper

  def default_url_options
     {host: 'example.com'}
  end
end

def action_view
  controller = ActionController::Base.new
  controller.request = ActionDispatch::TestRequest.new
  TaskActionView.new(Rails.root.join('app', 'views'), {}, controller)
end

action_view.render(:template =>"path/to/template")
```

This successfully included my application helper, tag helpers, and url helpers. You'll want to put your application/environments host properly into the default_url_options hash.

Comment: Thanks, Josh!!! Your workaround for ActionController and ActionDispatch works well with production environment & nested partials, while others answers works only in development env.

Answer (score -2):

This is what worked for me:

```
html = render_to_string(:index, layout: nil)
```

Comment: Does this work on rails 3.2 for you? I get undefined method trying this in console.