# How to use Rails 3 url_for method for the url parameter of $.ajax in jQuery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I'm using this javascript in substitution of remote_action:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#asset_category_id').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : '<%= escape_javascript(url_for :controller => :categories, :action => :update_subcategories) %>',
    data : 'category_id=' + this.value,
    success : function(data) {
        $('#subcategories_div').html(data);
        $('#subcategories_div').show();
            }
        })
    });
});
```

The url in the following line is not being formed correctly:

```
url : '<%= escape_javascript(url_for :controller => :categories, :action => :update_subcategories) %>'
```

It is being used literally:

http://localhost:3000/assets/%3C%=%20escape_javascript(url_for%20:controller%20=%3E%20:categories,%20:action%20=%3E%20:updates_subcategories)%20%%3E?category_id=156

How can I use url_for in jQuery? Is it possible?

If I use

```
url : '/categories/update_subcategories'
```

everything runs as expected.

**EDIT:**
I have tried the following things without luck.

Seems that I should use preprocessing ([guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing)) as noted by @Matzi and @Baldrick so my file should be main.js.erb. I have renamed this file in app/assets/javascripts. When I go to the assets/new view (where the file is needed) I get this error:

```
undefined method 'url_for' for #<#<Class:0x9853e4c>:0xab00c48>
```

I've tried to add these two lines to the assets_controller:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
```

Then I get:

```
undefined local variable or method `controller' for #<AssetsController:0xa40aaec>
```

In this line of the view:

```
<%= form_for(@asset) do |f| %>
```

I have also tried to add these lines to the new.html.erb file:

```
<%= include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper %>
<%= include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper %>
```

Then I get:

```
undefined method `include' for #<#<Class:0xab164d0>:0xab0183c>
```

As recommended by [Rails 3: How to render ERb template in rake task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262044/rails-3-how-to-render-erb-template-in-rake-task) in a similar case. I have tried the following includes in the view and controller with the same results:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers # brings ActionDispatch::Routing::UrlFor
include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
```

Another thing that I've tried, recommended by @Matzi is moving main.js.erb from app/assets/javascripts/ to app/views/assets. But in that case the Javascript in main.js.erb seems not to be loaded at the same time that the view new.html.erb. I've tried to rename main.js.erb to new.js.erb but the JS in the file seems not to be loaded neither.

I have though in using a JS to attach the handler and a js.erb to return the result but I need the url_for in the first JS in order to know where to call.

So the question remains, how can I use url_for in a js.erb that tries to attach a change handler to a field in a view?

Comment: Which file contains the `$(document).ready(function() { ...` code ?

Comment: @Baldrick the javascript `$(document).ready(function() { ...` is in app/assets/javascripts/main.js It is loaded for sure because if I use a literal url it runs as expected.

Comment: As said Matzi, it should be in a .js.erb file to process the ruby code in the js file. Read more about preprocessing here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that it is in a .js file, which is not interpreted by ruby. Try to put this code in a .js.erb file, and it will work for you.

UPDATE:

Asset is not for this kind of dynamic behavior, so you would better move it into some view, and render it, when needed. If you want to use it in an asset, you need to include the helpers in the .js.erb:

```
<% environment.context_class.instance_eval { include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper } %>
<% environment.context_class.instance_eval { include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper } %>
```

Comment: Wow. Preprocessing is so powerful. Now it seems that the ruby fragment in the js.erb file `<%= url_for(:controller => :categories, :action => :update_subcategories) %>` is being interpreted but I get a new error: `undefined method 'url_for' for #<#<Class:0x9853e4c>:0xab00c48>`. I have tried to add the line `include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper`to the view controller but I get another error: `undefined local variable or method 'controller' for #<AssetsController:0x994d12c>`. Any ideas? Why is not available url_for in the js.erb file?

Comment: Is this file in one of your view-s directory? In theory, rails link those files to the controller, allowing them to access the helper methods. So try to move your file, or just include these: `<% include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper %>` and `
<% include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper %>` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: I have probed what you say without luck. I have updated my question with the new things I've tried.

Comment: Okay, you definietly should move your code in a view, and render it. The asset is not for this. But, see the update. I hope it is the final. :)

Comment: Adding these two lines to the js.erb returns another error: `undefined local variable or method '_routes' for #<#<Class:0x9078290>:0xa1bee8c>` but I'm accepting your response **Asset is not for this kind of dynamic behavior** as I think I am definetly doing something wrong and I'm going to redesign the interaction. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you add two lines to the js.erb:

```
<% environment.context_class.instance_eval { include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper } %>
<% environment.context_class.instance_eval { include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper } %>
```

and get another `error: undefined local variable or method '_routes' for #<#<Class:0x9078290>:0xa1bee8c>`. Please replace above two lines to:

```
<% environment.context_class.instance_eval { include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers} %>
```