# Rails create static page from dynamic page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, static-pages

This seems like it should not be that hard but I am trying to figure out how to create a 'snapshot' or 'locked' view from one on my views.  This view currently is dynamic but I want to lock it so that any changes I make will not propagate until I want them too.

This would be a front facing page that should not get updated until I choose to update it such as by timestamping a field like updated_lock or something to that effect.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try `caches_action` in your controller.  It will create the static version and save it.  You could either create it in dev and checkin, or have it generated in production. You'd need to fine a way to delete it in production if it's not checked in.  Requires caching to be turned on.

If you are OK with checking it in - you can always save from the browser.

Basically - if there is a file in public at the same location as the view, it will be served instead of the dynamic one.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about maybe caching.  If I set that to never expire will it not update if I have new data or change the views?

Comment: You have a couple options for caching.  Sorry, I mistyped above, what you really want is page caching, not action caching here.  In that case, you'd use `caches_page`.  In rails 4, this will be in a gem if that's the way you want to go.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at that and see what it does.

Comment: OK, I found that caches_page ALMOST does exactly what I want.  This is a reach, but is there a way to cache the page WITHOUT visiting it?  In other words, set a view to use the caches_page and set the cache before anybody goes to that page?

Comment: Probably - I haven't done this, but you'd want to render a page and save it as a file.  You could likely do this through a rake task/cron job.  A quick google showed others doing this, eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262044/rails-3-how-to-render-erb-template-in-rake-task

Comment: This might work. That is essentially what happens when you visit the page and it is cached.  I will try this out :)

Comment: I marked you as the correct answer.  In a round about way it was your answers and some more things that made it work... [see here](http://bob-roberts.net/2014/03/30/pre-caching-a-page-in-rails/)